# How can i display different pre-filled google form URLs based on user input in Google Forms?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-forms

How can i display different pre-filled google form URLs based on user input in Google Forms?

**What i want to make:**

I want to make a google form that will ask users their ID/Batch number and then open up a pre-filled google form with data corresponding to the ID/Batch number submitted.

**What i have done:**

As of now, i already made pre-filled google forms using some websites and videos that i found as references. *eg of website i used: https://www.labnol.org/prefilled-google-forms-200601*
so right now i have a spreadsheet that is filled with URLs to pre-filled forms corresponding to the data rows.

i also have tested google form feature to display static URLs but i can't find how to export specific URLs from spreadsheet.

**what i want to ask for help:**

i want to know how can i pull the specific URLs in the spreadsheet then open/display it according to the ID/Batch number that users submit. i want the correct url to pop out right after submitting ID/batch number. is there's a way to use google form script for this? or do i need to learn Html?

Thank you. i appreciate any hint you can give me, i have never really explore google form before. sorry for my bad english.